# Puma::MiniSSL::SSLError: OpenSSL error: error:1417A0C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, openssl, puma

```
There is issue running rails server. It always shows Puma error MiniSSL.
    [57513] Puma starting in cluster mode...
    [57513] Environment: development
    [57513] Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3001
    [57513] Listening on ssl://0.0.0.0:3000?cert=config/ssl.crt&key=config/ssl.key verify_mode=none&no_tlsv1=false
    [57513] Use Ctrl C to stop
    [57513] Starting control server on unix:///tmp/puma-status-1588347759577-57513
    [57513] Worker 0 (pid: 57537) booted, phase: 0
    {2020-05-01 21:12:53 +0530: SSL error, peer: 127.0.0.1, peer cert: ,#<Puma::MiniSSL::SSLError: OpenSSL error: error:1417A0C1:SSL routines:tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher - 337092801>}`
```

I tried using previous version of puma and generating new ssl.

Comment: See https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1339.

Comment: @anothermh The issues discussed in github are related to SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO, whereas mine is SSL routines: tls_post_process_client_hello:no shared cipher

Comment: Did you try the solutions listed there?

Comment: Yes, I surely did tried the solutions there and various others available on other discussion platforms.But none of them worked for me. @anothermh

Comment: Then make a [mre] including all steps necessary to reproduce, including generation of certificates.

Comment: In my case: the key/crt files were not readable by the puma process. chmod helped.

Comment: Any solution available for this issue till now ? Adding read, write permissions even with execute permissions did not help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your permissions to 775 on /etc/letsencrypt/archive/your_domain

ie: chmod -R 775 /etc/letsencrypt/archive/your_domain

Comment: I tried `chmod 775 config/localhost.crt config/localhost.key` and still getting the same error

Comment: This was my issue. Thanks